# Simple Econometric question

Tags: econometrics

From LLN, we have $\text{plim}  Y_n=\mu$. Now you have $W_n=Y^3_n$, what is the probability limit of $W_n$?

Please help me answer this and thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

Comment: If you want to only find the probability limit, you can replace "plim" with "lim". Proving it involves probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have the answer. Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with $E(X_1)=\mu$ and $Var(X_1)=\sigma^2$ with $\mu,\sigma^2<\infty$. Define $Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$ By WLLN, $\text{plim}Y_n=\mu.$ Since $f(x)=x^3$ is a continuous function, by the continuous mapping theorem, $\text{plim}f(Y_n)=\text{plim}Y_n^3=f(\mu)=\mu^3.$